# Auto-detect the path to R.exe in c# on Windows

Tags: c#, r

I have a Windows Forms application in c#.NET. From my application I have to call some R commands. Before I run the R commands, I must check that R is installed on the user's computer. I also have to know the correct path to R.exe. On most Windows computers with the latest version of R, the path is: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\i386\Rgui.exe"` However, as you know there are many versions of R. Some users have R 2.15.1, other users have R 3.0.1 and so on.

Is there an easy method to "guess" the path to the latest version of R on the user's computer from c#.NET?

My idea is that my application will try to auto-detect the path to R and only in the case when R is not found, it will require the user to set the path to R manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First **list all directories** in "C:\Program Files\R", then you can check if for any version the **file "\bin\i386\Rgui.exe" exists** and if it exists, you can **choose your version** and do whatever you want to do with this path.

The [**System.IO.Directory**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [**System.IO.File**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be usefull.

Comment: a nice and straightforward solution. It won't work if the user installed R somewhere else than `C:\Program Files\R` but from my experience 95% of users install their R in the default C:\Program Files\R folder.

Comment: Else you can search the path where R is installed but i have no idea how to realize this so i didn't add it but you have reason

Comment: If you really want to list files to find R, better to use environment variables `%ProgramFiles%` and `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`.

Comment: answer below will give you the correct path even if installed in non default location

Answer (score 1):

You can find the installation path of all the R application from registry and then iterate over all the installation and find the latest version.

> HKLM/Software/Microsoft/CurrentVersion/Uninstall

Alternatively you could also use Installer APIs to get the installation path of all version of R. You will need the product code of R installer (which is generally public or you can get it from the MSI/registry)

Search for MsiGetProductInfo

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369558(VS.85).aspx

Comment: In registry, rather `InstallPath` in `HKLM\Software\R-core\R`. Note also `Wow6432Node`, `R32` and `R64`.

Comment: I never worked with the Windows registry in c#. Are there built-in methods in the .NET framework to find out what is in registry and check the `HKLM\Software\R-core\R`?

Comment: Yes. .net has pretty much everything you need to access your system.

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx for Registry API

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#RDotNet.NativeLibrary/NativeUtility.cs it does almost exactly what you want (R.dll instead of RGui.exe). You will find the functions `FindRPath` and the Windows-specific `FindRPathFromRegistry`. There is also code to find the R libraries on Linux and MacOS if you need to target these too.

Edit: you'll need to switch to the branch 'jperraud' to see the latest code; I cannot seem to create a direct hyperlink.